# Pycharm autocomplete with input()

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm

I'm trying to get user commands and execute them with python's input() and exec() and in the case that the user is using PyCharm, I want to the user to be able to autocomplete.

Autocomplete works in the python console as shown below.

[image]

But this same command does not work during the user input().

```
while True:
    command = input('Type command below\n')
    exec(command)
```

[image]

Is there an option that enables autocomplete during runs in PyCharm? Or is there another solution that would enable autocomplete during user input()?

Answer (score 1):

No, the feature only exists for code-auto completion. Since PyCharm does not "know"  what command you want to input in `command = input('Type command below\n')`, it cannot autocomplete it. It does not recognize your user input as code, but as user input, and therefore there is no way to autocomplete it.